# How do you add an extra value to a dictionary comprehension with enumerate?

Tags: python

I want to be able to access `my_cal[30]['r']` and get all the ranges. Then
access the first week with `my_cal[30]['wk']`

I tried this:

```py
new_ranges = {k:{'r':value,'week':i}, for i,(k,v) in enumerate(my_cal.items(),1)}
```

This is the *example* code:

```py
my_cal = { 'somekey':1,
            'ranges':{ 30:['08-1-2021'],
                      31: [   '08-2-2021',
                              '08-3-2021',
                              '08-4-2021',
                              '08-5-2021',
                              '08-6-2021',
                              '08-7-2021',
                              '08-8-2021'],
                      32: [   '08-9-2021',
                              '08-10-2021',
                              '08-11-2021',
                              '08-12-2021',
                              '08-13-2021',
                              '08-14-2021',
                              '08-15-2021']},
                      'lastkey':1}
```

Wanted result :

```py
my_cal = { 'somekey':1,
    'ranges':{ 30:'r':['08-1-2021'],'wk':1},
                31: {'r':[   '08-2-2021',
                              '08-3-2021',
                              '08-4-2021',
                              '08-5-2021',
                              '08-6-2021',
                              '08-7-2021',
                              '08-8-2021']},{'week',2},
                      'lastkey':1},
```

This print does not work in this example bellow because it complains about the tuple object
has no attribute items. It works fine in my
real code. I don't know why it converts it to a tuple.

```py
for key,value in my_cal.items():
    print("key is:", key, " value is:" , "\n")
```

Comment: Is `{'week', 2}` a typo? Should that be `'week': 2` in the containing dictionary? Also, `'wk': 1` should be `'week': 1`?

Comment: Isn't the result supposed to be `new_ranges`, not `my_cal`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be iterating over `my_cal['ranges'].items()`?

Comment: I don't see anything in the code you've posted that would change `my_cal` to a tuple. But I suspect you didn't copy the code accurately.

Comment: `value` should be `v`, and you shouldn't have a `,` after `{'r':value,'week':i}`.

Comment: Btw, your "Wanted result" doesn't match with the first line _"I want to be able to access `my_cal[30]['r']` and get all the ranges. Then access the first week with `my_cal[30]['wk']`."_ I've posted based on the _wanted_ result.

Comment: Your wanted result has `{ 30:'r':['08-1-2021'],'wk':1}`, which is a syntax error.

Comment: @Barmar You're right, sorry I did the best that I could to make an example for stackoverflow. It's not my actual code. It would be too complex  and long to include all of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some typos in your code, and one error:

1. In the definition of `my_cal`, you end it with a comma so that makes it the first element of a tuple. Remove that last trailing comma.
2. For `new_ranges`, you're doing `for (k, v) in ...` but then you refer to it as `value`.
3. An extra comma `,` after the *value* part of the dict comprehension.

Also, you should be iterating over `my_cal['ranges'].items()`, [as Barmar mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65963324/how-do-you-add-an-extra-value-to-a-dictionary-comprehension-with-enumerate/65963419#comment116628287_65963324). Anyway, if you change that line to:

```
new_ranges = {k: {'r': v, 'week': i} for i, (k, v) in enumerate(my_cal['ranges'].items(), 1)}
```

It gives you the `new_ranges` you expect. You can then assign it back to `ranges` in `my_cal` to get the form you want:

```py
my_cal['ranges'] = new_ranges

# output:

{'somekey': 1,
 'ranges': {30: {'r': ['08-1-2021'], 'week': 1},
            31: {'r': ['08-2-2021',
                       '08-3-2021',
                       '08-4-2021',
                       '08-5-2021',
                       '08-6-2021',
                       '08-7-2021',
                       '08-8-2021'],
                 'week': 2},
            32: {'r': ['08-9-2021',
                       '08-10-2021',
                       '08-11-2021',
                       '08-12-2021',
                       '08-13-2021',
                       '08-14-2021',
                       '08-15-2021'],
                 'week': 3}},
 'lastkey': 1}
```

---

*Edit:* Wrt *"I want to be able to access `my_cal[30]['r']` and get all the ranges. Then access the first week with `my_cal[30]['wk']`"* - then make the following changes *after* the `new_ranges = {...}` step:

```py
del my_cal['ranges']  # deletes the original `ranges` key
my_cal.update(new_ranges)  # adds the new ranges

# result:
{'somekey': 1,
 'lastkey': 1,
 30: {'r': ['08-1-2021'], 'week': 1},
 31: {'r': ['08-2-2021',
            '08-3-2021',
            '08-4-2021',
            '08-5-2021',
            '08-6-2021',
            '08-7-2021',
            '08-8-2021'],
      'week': 2},
 32: {'r': ['08-9-2021',
            '08-10-2021',
            '08-11-2021',
            '08-12-2021',
            '08-13-2021',
            '08-14-2021',
            '08-15-2021'],
      'week': 3}}
```

Comment: And if you want `wk` instead of `week`, change that in the `new_range` loop. (I used the version from your original code.)

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work ```new_ranges = {k: {'r': v, 'week': i} for i, (k, v) in enumerate(my_cal['ranges'].items(), 1)}``` but I lost somekey and lastkey, do I manually just add them ? How can I include them in this comprehension ?

Comment: You don't lose them. When you do `my_cal['ranges'] = new_ranges`, it only updates `ranges`, not the other two keys, those remain as is. That's in my answer.